# Django get_or_create() returning odd behaviour

Tags: python, django

I'm running into a strange error when trying to get or create an object through `get_or_create()`

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "(<CaseStatus: CaseStatus object (13)>,)": "PatientCase.status" must be a "CaseStatus" instance.
```

**build_case function**

```
def build_case(obj):

    data = {
        "case": {
            "case_id": obj.case_id,
            "uuid": obj.uuid.hex,
            "owner": {
                "uuid": obj.owner.userprofile.uuid.hex
            },
            "status": {
                "uuid": obj.status.uuid.hex,
                "message": obj.status.status,
                "extra_data": obj.status.extra_data,
            },
            "patient": {
                "uuid": obj.patient.uuid.hex,
                "details": {
                    "full_name": obj.patient.full_name,
                    "date_of_birth": obj.patient.date_of_birth.strftime(
                        "%Y-%m-%d"),
                    "practice": {
                        "uuid": obj.patient.practice.uuid.hex,
                        "name": obj.patient.practice.name
                    }
                }
            },
            "start_date": obj.start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
            "case_photos": [
                photo.file_path for photo in obj.case_photos.all()],
            "forum_permalink": obj.forum_permalink,
            "phase": obj.phase,
            "in_retention": obj.in_retention
        }
    }

    if obj.upper_arch:
        data['case']['upper_arch'] = {
            "uuid": obj.upper_arch.uuid.hex,
            "name": obj.upper_arch.name
        }

    if obj.lower_arch:
        data['case']['lower_arch'] = {
            "uuid": obj.lower_arch.uuid.hex,
            "name": obj.lower_arch.name
        }

    return data
```

**object**

```
{
  'Type': 'Notification',
  'MessageId': 'e4ad7fc2-1483-48d7-94be-624aa26b4fff',
  'TopicArn': '...',
  'Subject': 'Hello',
  'Message': {
    'type': 'ias.case.updated',
    'content': {
      'case': {
        'case_id': 'XO1GBRP',
        'uuid': 'f7c8799d793a426bad50fd1f325de6bf',
        'owner': {
          'uuid': '6f08398e91f14422bb4ac7dffb2e093a'
        },
        'status': {
          'uuid': '12d2277ed3c7450b9c65ee85ed0935a3',
          'message': 'processing',
          'extra_data': None
        },
        'patient': {
          'uuid': 'b9b964ea2ada4b049f8812e1c06259b1',
          'details': {
            'practice': {
              'uuid': 'e0ed87aacbc54fda85639c0d32d1c693',
              'name': ''
            }
          }
        },
        'start_date': '2019-01-14',
        'case_photos': [

        ],
        'forum_permalink': None,
        'phase': None,
        'in_retention': False,
        'upper_arch': {
          'uuid': '371435d0e36c45adb6e01c659472f3d8',
          'name': 'Inman Aligner'
        }
      }
    },
    'origin': 'ias_cs'
  },
}
```

**function processing the data**

```
def get_case_status(status_data):
    defaults = {
        "status": status_data['message'],
        "status_message": generate_status_message(status_data['message']),
    }
    if status_data.get('extra_data'):
        defaults['extra_data'] = status_data['extra_data']

    status, created = CaseStatus.objects.get_or_create(
        uuid=status_data['uuid'],
        defaults = defaults
    )

    return status
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/ias_lab/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/ias_lab/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/ias_lab/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/ias_lab/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/ias_lab/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 45, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/ias_lab/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/ias_lab/lib/python3.7/site-packages/braces/views/_forms.py", line 24, in dispatch
    return super(CsrfExemptMixin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/ias_lab/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "./pubsub/views.py", line 141, in post
    patient_case.status = status,
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/ias_lab/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 210, in __set__
    self.field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name,
ValueError: Cannot assign "(<CaseStatus: CaseStatus object (2)>,)": "PatientCase.status" must be a "CaseStatus" instance.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `status_data['message']` in your view. It looks as if it is a tuple `(<CaseStatus: CaseStatus object (13)>,)` rather than a status object `<CaseStatus: CaseStatus object (13)>`.

You might have a comma in your code which is making `status` a tuple, for example:

```
status = CaseStatus(...),
```

We can't tell that though, because you haven't included the full traceback or the rest of your code that sets `status_data`.

Comment: What is being returned couldn’t possible be a tuple though. Granted get_or_create does return a tuple but as you can see i have already assigned variables to them. Had I returned (status, created) then yes it would be a tuple. I can’t see why status would then be an additional tuple? That would mean get or create is returning ((status,), true) would it not?

Comment: I think the error is in the data you are passing *to* `get_or_create`, not what you are doing with the result. But as I said before, we can’t tell where the problem is because you haven’t included the traceback.

Comment: I will provide this on Monday when I get back in the office. Thanks

Comment: I've updated the original question with more data. I still can't see any tuple being provided in the example. It's only the return from get_case_status that seems to be doing this.

Comment: It's right there in your traceback: `patient_case.status = status,`, pubsub/views.py line 141.

Comment: GOD DAMN COMMAS!! haha thanks jason I've been staring at that for days!!!